# Azure AD B2C Signature Hash with Google Managed app Signing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, google-play-console, android-signing

Is anybody using Azure AD B2C and Google Play who has selected the "Let Google manage and protect your app signing (recommended)" option?

I don't know how to follow the Azure portal directions on "Generating a production Signature Hash" in this circumstance. The instructions are to run this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias SIGNATURE_ALIAS -keystore PATH_TO_KEYSTORE | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I don't have a SIGNATURE_ALIAS or PATH_TO_KEYSTORE in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, which I found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/931#issuecomment-632837482).

Go to the app in the Google Play Console and in the Release section of the menu options you will see:

[image]

The main screen will show:

[image]

Download the certificate and run this in the directory of the downloaded certificate:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in deployment_cert.der -outform der | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```